# Minimizing objective function returns the same initial inputs as output

Tags: python, r, optimization, scipy

I am currently replicating the distance to default function from R (https://rdrr.io/rforge/ifrogs/src/R/dtd.R) into python. The known variables are `mcap`, `debt`, `vol`, and `r`, and the unknown are `V` and `sV`. The initial value of `V` is set as `mcap+debt` , and `sV` is set as `(mcap * vol) / debt`.

This [link](https://rdrr.io/rforge/ifrogs/f/inst/doc/dtd.pdf) provides some more details about the objective function we are trying to minimize.

I am having some trouble with the `optimize_obj_function` step (at the end). Any help with idenitifying the mistake I am making would be greatly appreciated! The result from the minimize function with inputs defined as follows is below:

optimize_obj_function returns the same initial values set

```
fun: array(0.)
hess_inv: <2x2 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
jac: array([0., 0.])
message: b'ERROR: NO FEASIBLE SOLUTION'
nfev: 0
nit: 0
status: 2
success: False
x: array([1.5e+04, 8.0e-01])
```

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import minimize 

mcap=10000
debt=5000
vol=0.4
r=0.1
V=mcap+debt
sV=(mcap * vol) / debt
T=1

unknown_vars = [V,sV]
known_vars = [mcap,debt,vol,T]

#Solving reverse Black-Scholes for market value of asset and asset volatility  
def d1(V, debt, sV, T):
    num = (np.log(V/debt)) + ((0.5*sV**2)*T)
    #num = (np.log(V/debt)) + ((r_f + 0.5*sV**2)*T)
    den = sV * np.sqrt(T)    
    return num/den

def d2(V, debt, sV, T):
    d2 = d1(V, debt, sV, T) - sV*np.sqrt(T)
    return d2

unknown_vars = [V,sV]
known_vars = [mcap,debt,vol,T]
    
def objective_function(unknown_vars,known_vars):
    mcap, debt, vol, T = known_vars
    V,sV = unknown_vars
    rho=1
    e1 = -mcap + V*norm.cdf(d1(V,debt*rho,sV,T)) - rho*debt*norm.cdf(d2(V,rho*debt,sV,T))
    e2 = -vol*mcap + sV*V*norm.cdf(d1(V,debt*rho,sV,T))
    obj_fun = (e1*e1) + (e2*e2)
    return obj_fun

''' Description of input variables of objective function:
x[0] = V = starting value of market value of equity    
x[1] = sV = starting value of asset volatility of equity    
x[2] = mcap = market cap of equity (CRSP vars = abs(PRC) x SHROUT)
x[3] = debt*rho = book value of debt * rho
x[4] = vol = volatility of asset returns
x[5] = T = time to maturity (1 year)
'''

#Solve for asset value and asset volatility - estimated from the market value 
#and volatility of equity, and the book value of liabilities. Minimize the error term

bnds = ((known_vars[0], 0), (np.inf,np.inf))
optimize_obj_function = minimize(fun=objective_function, 
                                 x0=unknown_vars,
                                 args=(known_vars),
                                 method='L-BFGS-B', 
                                 bounds=bnds)

optimize_obj_function.x # array([1.5e+04, 8.0e-01]) -> same as inputs
```

Comment: Can you provide import statements so we can run your code?  E.g. for `norm` and `minimize`

Comment: @Bill scipy imports added

Comment: There's still a problem with your code.  I think you may be missing a close-parenthesis on the objective_function definition.

Comment: Pretty sure my mistake is in the minimize step, I'm just not sure what part I am defining wrong

Comment: I get `ValueError: LBFGSB - one of the lower bounds is greater than an upper bound.`  Please make sure your code reproduces the problem you want us to fix.

Comment: @Bill apologies. The code should run now

Answer (score 0):

In your minimize statement you are not passing the objective function.  Instead, you are passing the following float value:

```
print(objective_function(unknown_vars,known_vars))
# 29679735.772182897
```

To pass an objective function to scipy.minimize you do this:

```
optimize_obj_function = minimize(fun=objective_function, 
                                 x0=unknown_vars,
                                 args=(known_vars),
                                 method='L-BFGS-B', 
                                 bounds=bnds)
```

Note that your objective function must have the arguments that minimize is expecting.

Also, ***your bounds are incorrectly organized***.  There may be other things wrong with your code, (I gave up at this point).

As you pointed out below, the bounds should be

```
bnds = ((known_vars[0], np.inf), (0, np.inf))
```

Suggest reading the documentation on [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy-optimize-minimize) and maybe trying a few of the examples there first before trying your own problem.

Comment: The optimize_obj_function you have recommended is exactly what I have done?

Comment: Looks like you edited the code, so yes, it is correct now.  Now fix the bounds (see the documentation on how to organize them).  After that I found it converged to this solution: `x: array([1.49999905e+04, 2.66669643e-01])`. Is this what you expected or not?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am after!

Comment: Wow, my mistake was fixed very easy. Thanks for your help and pointing out the problem regarding the incorrectly specified bounds. Was suppose to be this -> bnds = ((known_vars[0], np.inf), (0,np.inf)). If you want to update your answer I can accept it :) You've been very helpful :)

Comment: The strange thing is, why you didn't get the traceback `ValueError: LBFGSB - one of the lower bounds is greater than an upper bound.`?

Comment: Not too sure, might have specified something wrong. Probably an error on my part

Comment: What do you get when you run the code in your question?

Comment: fun: 5.8927870940129744e-09
 hess_inv: <2x2 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([-1.05461963e-05, -1.00775788e-02])
  message: b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
     nfev: 108
      nit: 12
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([1.49999905e+04, 2.66669643e-01])

Comment: That is not what I get when I run the code in your question above.

Comment: Odd. Is the output the same as what you got when it converged for you?

Comment: When I run the code in your question, I get the traceback message in my comment above.  I am trying to figure out why you don't get that.